# How can I get the method of an interface and its return type and param type from an external class?

Tags: php

I want to get int from an external class.

```
interface FooInterface
{
    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int;
    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId(int $id);
}
```

1. I would like to know the return type of the getters to dynamically format the value.
2. I would like to know the parameter type of the setters to dynamically initialize it.

I need to do it this way because the properties are not initialized, because they are of an object type and their real value is in the interfaces.

```
class Foo extends FooAbstract implements FooInterface
{
    use BuilderFoo;// here are the FooInterface methods
    
    protected function getParamTypeValue(string $functionName)
    {
        $reflectionParams = (new ReflectionFunction($functionName))->getParameters();//local.ERROR: Function setId() does not exist
        return $reflectionParams[0]->getType();
    }
    
    protected function getReturnTypeValue(string $functionName)
    {
        return (new ReflectionFunction($functionName))->getReturnType();//local.ERROR: Function getId() does not exist
    }
}
```

But I get the error: "local.ERROR: Function getId() does not exist" and
"local.ERROR: Function setId() does not exist".

Comment: Some more description to explain in more detail what you are actually trying to do will help us to help you

Comment: Is it possible to use a trait to satisfy an interface?

Comment: Yes, I have several traits so as not to extend the class too much.

Comment: If you do not satisfy the contract you always are going to have an error. You would have to use a dedicated Trait or Extends an Abstract class.

Comment: So while the only solution I can think of is to initialize the parameter in the setters. This way I call a method that traverses the interface and the setters initialize themselves.
public function setId(string $id = 0): self

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get the return type of a declared method inside an interface is checking that value after implementation of the Interface.

Interfaces are not instatiables are contracts that other classes has to satisfy.

so here is an example.

```
interface I{
  public function test():int;
}

class TestClass implements I {

  public function test():int{
    return 5;
  }


}

$obj= new TestClass;

gettype($obj->test()) //"integer"
```

I hope this answer your question.